# user object with TreeNode in C#

Tags: c#, treenode, user-object

Can i tie a user object to a TreeNode in C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the Tag property to store any user object for a particular tree node.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx

```
TreeNode node = CreateATreeNode();
node.Tag = myStateObject;
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I'd like to add that on a _AfterSelect event use ((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode.Tag;